# Using a dropdown list to get image names from a folder and applying them to an image url

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to apply the name of the image but the images are not loading.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string[] str = new string[] { "Select", "Anniversary", "Birthday",
        "Graduation", "Sympathy" };
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        DDl1.Items.Add(str[i]);
    }  // this Loop creates the items in the drop down list

    {
        string str = DDl1.Text;
        Image1.ImageUrl="~/Media"+str+".png";
    } // This is how i was trying to call the images from the Media folder in my project
```

Comment: You'll need to add the 2nd part to the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the dropdown. There could be other issues, like you probably need a slash after the word Media in your url string.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
Image1.ImageUrl="~/Media"+str+".png";
```

to

```
Image1.ImageUrl="~/Media/"+str+".png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` on your `<asp:DropDownList>` and add `AutoPostBack="True"`.

In Code behind event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` put the code as below:

`string str = DDl1.Text;` or `string str = DDl1.SelectedText;`

```
Image1.ImageUrl="~/Media/"+str+".png";
```

I hope this would help you.